Draggable Marker on HARP - Performance Issues
After recreating demo from ['here'] and changed app to use HARP from ['here'] the demo became unusable due to performance issues [checked on chrome and edge].
There should be no visible downsides when using HARP [performance should be at the same level]
Thanks for help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
